# How can i fetch image from Firebase FireStore into carouselSlider Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I want to fetch images from firebase firestore collection , not from assets

How can i do it ?

[i want to display sellers sellerAvatarUrl in carousel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siQnH.png)

[here is my carouselSlider](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpog1.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Image.network(url)` instead of `Image.asset`. You can find more information in doc here: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/images/network-image